# C# - How can understand that I selected the address bar of chrome?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, mouseevent, virtual-keyboard, address-bar

How can I see programmaticaly in C# that I select with the mouse the address bar of chrome?
When I click the address bar of chrome I want to show up a virtual keyboard.
I found how to get the url but I think i am looking for a mouse event

Comment: You would most likely have to write an Extension.  That said, I didn't find anything in the [Extensions API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index) that would allow you to hook an OnEnter event in the address bar.

Comment: Trough some kind of chrome API or some dark hackery where you read specific memory address of chrome, but that would really be the last option.